# Sorting a multidimensional array using "array_multisort" does not work as desired

Tags: php

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
array (
        0 =>
            array (
                'UserName' => 'AdminB',
                'UserGUID' => 'a986fee9-35b4-47d7-a5ef-cfb7595356e0',
            ),
        1 =>
            array (
                'UserName' => 'AdminA',
                'UserGUID' => '9eb91d02-2a36-4db2-a0d4-ce583004b9b2',
            ),
        2 =>
            array (
                'UserName' => 'Administrator',
                'UserGUID' => '0f6697f5-f9d4-4883-afa0-0458c02090b2',
            ),
        3 =>
            array (
                'UserName' => '_UserB',
                'UserGUID' => 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054',
            ),
        4 =>
            array (
                'UserName' => '_UserE',
                'UserGUID' => '5ca9359d-5492-4b22-bd02-209f104e61d3',
            ),
        5 =>
            array (
                'UserName' => 'krbtgt',
                'UserGUID' => '797d3eb1-cb5e-4f59-b1d1-120a6b099c3b',
            ),
    );
```

I want to sort it after "UserName" and also re-index it.
I tried `array_multisort` for sorting like this:

```
array_multisort( $MyArray, SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR );
```

The Array gets re-indexed, but the sorting is not as desired:

```
Is            | Should
------------------------------
AdminA        | _UserB
AdminB        | _UserE
Administrator | AdminA
_UserB        | AdminB
_UserE        | Administrator
krbtgt        | krbtgt
```

I tried different sort-flags like "SORT_STRING", but this does not work, because of "Array to string conversion".
I also tried to use "array_column", but without success.

```
array_multisort( array_column( $MyArray, "UserName" ), SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING );
```

Is there a One-Liner to do this task?

Thank you

Comment: If you only want to sort by username, then what makes you think you need multisort?

Comment: I mainly used it, because of its re-index functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-index"? Once sorted, the logical order will be the physical order.

Comment: When using asort() for example the "UserName" column gets sorted, but the keys are not in order. (1-0-2-3-4-5) By "re-index" I mean, that the keys also get in order. (0-1-2-3-4-5)

Comment: Ok. I didnt know that. I usually use `usort` and just provide an anonymous function to handle the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `usort` with string comparsion function `strcasecmp`:

```php
usort($myArray, function($a, $b){ 
    return strcasecmp($a['UserName'], $b['UserName']);
});
```

Comment: Working fine. Thank you very much!